# Networking starts up but interface has no IP

Tags: networking, network-interface, init-script

I have a box that is supposed to run headless.
When I boot and manually run `/etc/init.d/networking` everything starts fine.
When I add it to  my startup scripts (`/etc/rcS.d`) as placed by `sysv-rc-conf` the network starts up OK. `ifconfig` shows everything is working right, except for some reason there is no IP assigned to the interface.

PS: These are statically assigned addresses.

Comment: What OS do you use (distro and version)? How is your box supposed to get an address? With DHCP? In that case, is your dhcp client service running?

Comment: Is the device setup so that it's got `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` in your `ifcfg-eth0` file? Assuming it's `eth0`.

Answer (score 1):

Configure manually the network interfaces,
network interfaces configuration stored in:

> /etc/network/interfaces

Here you can configure interface to use DHCP or assign static ip address:
DHCP:

> iface eth0 inet dhcp

static:

> iface eth0 inet static
>   address 192.168.2.2
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>   network 192.168.2.0
>   broadcast 192.168.2.255
>   gateway 192.168.2.1
>   dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1

see more config options in man page:

> man interfaces

Comment: Explain to me how /etc/network/interfaces can be improperly configured if I can get the network to start by manually running  /etc/init.d/networking?

Comment: My interfaces is also configured with static IP.
Try to put "auto eth0" berfore interface declaration "iface eth0 ...", i think it solvs the problem.

Comment: Careful! That is *very* distribution (even version) specific! Check your distribution's configuration guides for the network, or edit your question to add those details.

Answer (score 1):

In the last case create a network setup script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.2
route add default gw 192.168.2.1
echo "nameserver 192.168.2.1" > /etc/resvolv.conf
```

and place to /etc/rcX.d/99netstart
and add permisson to run

```
chmod 700 /etc/rcX.d/99netstart
```

replace the IPs for your configuration

and in "rcX.d" the X for the runlevel hat you use (if you not modified, it is 2 ).

Answer (score 0):

For a CentOS/Fedora/Redhat variant OS ensure you have the lines in the file 
`/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-interfacename`:

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
```